Given that a section header is inside a tcolorbox, how can I make it such that the color of the box cycles through 4 colors?
Using xpatch and tcolorbox. I got my section headers to appear inside a tcolorbox, however, I want said headers to cycle through 4 different colours, without loosing the properties of the section environment.
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[top = 2.5cm, bottom= 1.8cm, left = 2.5cm, right = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{inchworm}{rgb}{0.7, 0.93, 0.36}

\newtheorem{df}{Definition}[section]

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\sectionbox}{}{\PatchFailed}

\newcommand*{\sectionbox}[1]{
\begin{tcolorbox}
                 [
                  colback=inchworm!90!white,
                  colframe=inchworm
                 ]
   \Large\textbf{#1}
\end{tcolorbox} 
} 
\begin{document}

\chapter{AS1 CLASS NOTES}

\section{Propositional logic} \lipsum[3][2-4]
\begin{df}
    \lipsum[2][1-2] 
\end{df}

\section{Inferences}
\begin{df}
    \lipsum[10][1-3]
\end{df}


\end{document}


welcome! please complete your code so we can compile it and have something to work with.

Sure! It should be up there by  now

You could use a colour series:
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[top = 2.5cm, bottom= 1.8cm, left = 2.5cm, right = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{inchworm}{rgb}{0.7, 0.93, 0.36}

\newtheorem{df}{Definition}[section]

\definecolorseries{foo}{rgb}{last}{red}{blue}
\resetcolorseries[4]{foo}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\sectionbox}{}{\PatchFailed}
\colorlet{bar}{foo!!+}

\newcommand*{\sectionbox}[1]{
\colorlet{bar}{foo!!+}
\begin{tcolorbox}
                 [
                  colback=bar,
                  colframe=bar
                 ]
   \Large\textbf{#1}
\end{tcolorbox} 
} 
\begin{document}

\section{Propositional logic}
\section{Inferences}
\section{Propositional logic}
\section{Inferences}
\section{Propositional logic}
\section{Inferences}
\section{Propositional logic}
\section{Inferences}

\end{document}



If you would like to choose all four colours separately you could borrow the colour cycling code from the rainbow beamer colour theme:
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[top = 2.5cm, bottom= 1.8cm, left = 2.5cm, right = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{inchworm}{rgb}{0.7, 0.93, 0.36}

\newtheorem{df}{Definition}[section]

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\sectionbox}{}{\PatchFailed}

\def\rainbowcolors{red,blue,green,yellow}
\ExplSyntaxOn

% list to store colour list
\clist_new:N \l_rainbow_clist
\clist_set:Nx \l_rainbow_clist \rainbowcolors

\newcommand*{\sectionbox}[1]{
\colorlet{bar}{
  \clist_item:Nn \l_rainbow_clist {
    \int_eval:n {
      \int_mod:nn { \value{section} }{ 
        \clist_count:N \l_rainbow_clist
      } + 1
    }
  }
}
\begin{tcolorbox}
                 [
                  colback=bar,
                  colframe=bar
                 ]
   \Large\textbf{#1}
\end{tcolorbox} 
} 
\ExplSyntaxOff  
\begin{document}

\section{Propositional logic}
\section{Inferences}
\section{Propositional logic}
\section{Inferences}
\section{Propositional logic}
\section{Inferences}
\section{Propositional logic}
\section{Inferences}

\end{document}


